# Перенаправление стандартного ввода из конвейера

Tags: c

Помогите,пожалуйста,найти ошибку. Программа работает правильно,но не завершается....

Вот условие: Написать программу,которая создает не именованный канал, запускает в качестве внешней программы команду `grep` со строкой `"222"` в качестве параметра, и причем её стандартный поток ввода перенаправлен на чтение из канала. В родительском процессе организовать запись в канал строк, содержащие десятичное представление чисел от 1 до 3000

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int fd[2],i;
    pipe(fd);
    if(fork()==0){
        dup2(fd[0],0);
        close(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        execlp("grep","grep","222",NULL);
        perror("WTF!?");
        exit(1);
    }
    dup2(fd[1],1);
    for(i=1;i<=3000;i++)
        printf("%d\n",i);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте к остальным `close()`

```
close(1);
```

т.е. закройте дескриптор, получаемый через `dup2()`.

Вообще, `close(fd[1])` нужен, иначе счетчик ссылок на "принимающий конец" pipe остается ненулевым и grep не получает EOF. В принципе, его можно вызвать сразу после `dup2()`.

Закрывать ли `fd[0]`?
В данном случае это не обязательно, на логику программы не повлияет, при exit все дескрипторы система закроет и ресурсы освободятся.

**UPDATE**

Возможен и такой вариант, использующий `fdopen()` вместо `dup2()` (и вообще, оставляющий дескриптор 1 в покое)

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
    FILE *f = fdopen(fd[1], "w");
    for(i=1;i<=3000;i++)
      fprintf(f, "%d\n",i);
    fclose(f); // fd[1] будет закрыт в этом вызове
    wait(0);
...
```

Comment: Спасибо!Все заработало,но можите ,пожалуйста,поподробнее объяснить,что вы имели в виду:                                                                                            Вообще, close(fd[1]) нужен, иначе счетчик ссылок на "принимающий конец" pipe остается ненулевым и grep не получает EOF. В принципе, его можно вызвать сразу после dup2().                                       Просто наш преподователь запрещает делать close(1):(

Comment: @mango44, странный преподаватель. Впрочем, поэкспериментируйте сами, и покажите ему результаты. Может поймет, что без `close(1)` после цикла записи pipe остается открыт (т.к. есть дескрипторы через которые  можно в него писать) и поэтому grep не завершается (висит на своем read(0, ...)). А по поводу счетчиков ссылок на объекты ядра (в нашем случае дескриптор записи  в pipe в системной таблице) лучше для начала почитать (самому преподавателю?) какую-нибудь книжку о системном программировании в \*nix, поскольку тема довольно длинная.

Comment: @mango44, впрочем, возможно Вы немного перепутали и в задании предлагалось использовать не dup2, а fdopen. Тогда, см.  **update** и выбирайте стратегию борьбы на свой вкус.

Comment: можно ли как-нибудь с вами связаться(с помощью почты,профиля в соц. сети или еще как-нибудь) для личной просьбы?

Comment: @mango44, напишите в avp210159@mail.ru и в письмо положите URL сюда, а то я могу не понять о чем речь. (только поймите правильно, я заранее ничего не обещаю)